# Publish on facebook fan page when the user is not logged-in

Tags: facebook-graph-api, access-token, facebook-page

I'm using the Graph API code that uses an `acces_token` and an `id_page` with permissions to post to a fan page. It works as long as the user is logged, but when I log out the `access_token` expires and I can't publish to fan page.

How can I make my application to be able to publish at any time, even when the user is not logged in?

This is my code:

```
<?php
$page_access_token = 'AAAFNxxxx';
$page_id = '15203xxx'; 
$data['picture'] = "https://www.google.it/logos/2012/moby_dick12-hp.jpg";
$data['link'] = "http://www.google.it/";
$data['message'] = "Test";
$data['description'] = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
$data['access_token'] = $page_access_token;
//curl connection
$post_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$page_id.'/feed';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $post_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$return = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [extended token](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/#extend_token) to post when the user has logged out, by retrieving the same exchanging you own client_id (your app_id), your app_secret, and the non-expired, short-lived access_token

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?             
client_id=APP_ID&
client_secret=APP_SECRET&
grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Answer (score -2):

Make pending posts in your word press blog, connect your blog with networkbloggers and fanpage.So it will be: Your awaesome WP + Networkbloggers = post on Facebook Fanpage
That must  work i'm using it long time every time my post enter on my facebook fan page no need app. or something more complicate

Comment: This clearly won't work for having an application do this automatically.